# "Git Proxy", not HTTP proxy

Tags: git, github, proxy

I'm looking for solutions of the following problem. 
Suppose you have the service and it works with code base of OpenSource projects distributing via GitHub repos. You have server, which periodically updates local working copies from bunch of GitHub repos, on updates issued. You have a lot of machines (developers, application workers), which updates theirs' own local working copies from that server, not from GitHub. I need infrastructure/technology works familiar with my description. 
Do Git provides it out-of-the box? 
I'm sorry if description is wordy, but I have Git skills only as developer, not as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean out-of-the-box for this case? It can be reached just writing a few *bash* scripts, which shell be assigned to run with *cron*. I did the similar arch, it just time-by-time updated the host *git* repository, from an *svn* repositore with one-side conversion. Of course, you should set up the *cron*, and *bash* script calls from a proper user to have proper rights for the host *git* repo. Prepare you *bash* scripts as if they would replay your actions on a *git* repo.

Comment: Thanks! Git remotes solve my problem, and some bash scripts will work pretty fine I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a distributed version control system, which is pretty much exactly what you're asking for.  There is no difference between an upstream repository and a local repository, so you can certainly treat the repository hosted on your server as the upstream repositories for all your developers.

Some articles that discuss distributed workflows:

- http://www.freemanmobile.com/2013/10/git-basic-guide-0.html
- http://hades.name/blog/2010/01/17/git-your-friend-not-foe/
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows